# android change alignment programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<customfonts.RoundedImageView
android:id="@+id/profile"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ssz"/>

<customfonts.MyTextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@drawable/circulo"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/profile"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:text="2"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textSize="13sp"
android:id="@+id/num" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the result

[image]

as we see the textView alignment to left
now when i change it programmatically to right its will be like this

[image]

on the left side alignment to right in xml and on the right alignment programmatically why there are space between imageView and textView

what i use for alignment right in xml

```
android:layout_alignRight="@id/profile"
```

and what i use for  alignment to right programmatically

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)Num.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 0);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.profile);
        Num.setLayoutParams(params);
```

where `Num` its the TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please give negative margin like -20dp

Comment: i give it and now good expect when alignment to left its shape be different
see image
`https://s32.postimg.org/flwo4diwl/Capture.png`